# Jenkins Lint Plugin not picking up results

Tags: android, jenkins, android-lint

I installed the [Android Lint Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Lint+Plugin) plugin in jenkins and activated it in my Android project build (which is build with maven). Then I added "execute shell" as post build action with the command

```
os_opts="-Djava.awt.headless=true" lint --xml lint-results.xml .
```

as described. The lint-results.xml file is created in the root workspace folder and it contains results. But somehow the plugin does not pick up the results and display them anywhere.

I already tried  configuring different file names and locations for the result xml file but that did not seem to help.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Certain plugins plot their results not on the main job page, but on the actual page for a particular build. Stupid question: Have you checked there?

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I looked in every sub page of the job and its builds but I could not see anything

Answer (score 1):

Given that lint-results.xml files are generated with `lint` or `gradle build`, you need to check that "Publish Android Lint results" step is added as "Post-build Actions"